# How to get own mobile number

Tags: android

I am fetching my mobile number but it is giving null. I am using below code snippet. Help me to solve this problem:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String number = tm.getLine1Number();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee you can read your number. If you are getting `null` then you out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, What you are doing is the only way. But many devices don't allow user's number to be fetched. So there is no robust way to find out user's phone number through code. Have a plan B. Something like if it returns null, ask user to enter the number or something.

Answer (score 0):

If number return null means, your phone number not register in your mobile.For that you can use the sim card serial number.It is unique number.

```
  TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
```

I hope this will helps you.

Comment: yeah correct, i am getting serial number but i want to show my mobile number

Comment: are you using your phone number for uniqueness .I think so you can use this number(SimSerialNumber).

Comment: some time happen like that means we forget our number thats why i want to show number